# How to make get_dummies work in place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I apply `get_dummies` on my `DataFrame` to generate dummy variables. It creates a new `DataFrame`. How can I change my original `DataFrame` instead?

This works, but is there a better way?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [ 'female', 'male']})
data1 = pd.get_dummies(data, columns = ['gender'])
# data is still unchanged
data.drop(data.columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
data[data1.columns] = data1
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code, you are creating a new dataframe, then removing all of the data from the old dataframe, and then putting the new data back into the old dataframe.

Instead of your last three lines of code, you can just say:

```
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns = ['gender'])
```

The get_dummies function creates a new dataframe and saves it in the place of the old one.  This is functionally the same as your code, but it is much easier to understand.

Comment: What about if you don't want the `get_dummies()` function to split the values into separate columns? I wouldn't want a `gender_male` column and a `gender_female` column....

Comment: Say drop_first=True